# How to change the position of Dynamic View's Search bar to the left (CSS CODE)

Tags: css, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

By default, the search bar in Blogger's Dynamic View is the right. Well I changed my blog's language to Arabic (In Arabic, we write from right to left unlike English) so the title and description are moved to the right side, but the search bar didn't move to the left, so they are on top of each other. I don't want to change the position of the title and description, just the search bar. Thanks a lot :)
Note: I know this website is about programming and I am asking for a CSS code to do it so yeas this is in the right place :)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to template,customise,advanced and
Add this

```
#search{
margin-right: 125px !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line in your template style to put the search section in the left side of your title:

```
 float: left;
```